# Thread queue in Swift

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

When user click at button i perform 15 background tasks with some function:

```
let priority = DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(priority, 0)) {
    myfunc()
}
```

So i have tested this on my phone, and when i click on button couple times, i got a lot of threads and phone lagged for a minute...

So do i need create Array with task queue and for example limit number of threads to 5 or 10 or swift has standard instruments for this ?

Comment: Is `myfunc()` an expensive operation? How are you performing the 15 tasks - in a for loop?

Comment: What you need is `NSOperationQueue`. It has `maxConcurrentOperationCount`. You can set it whatever you want or just leave it by default.

Comment: > Is myfunc() an expensive operation? How are you performing the 15 tasks - in a for loop?

yes

Comment: > What you need is NSOperationQueue. It has maxConcurrentOperationCount. You can set it whatever you want or just leave it by default.

but i want to limit only for this tasks

Comment: There are fifteen background tasks that you perform each time a button is clicked? It seems that running 15 tasks per button click would be the problem, not _how_ you do it.

Comment: No you don't need an `Array` - just use a standard Cocoa `NSOperationQueue` for this function as @sahara108 has suggested. You can then use a different `NSOperationQueue` or GCD for other operations. You might want to use the profiler to find out what is causing the slowdown during an optimisation pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for comments, this is works:

```
let backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()
backgroundQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 5
for i in 0...100 {
   backgroundQueue.addOperationWithBlock(){
       self.somefunc()
  }
}
```